# How can I make export permanent?

Tags: windows, shell, export

If I set a variable using `export` and then get out of the command line and go back to it, it no longer has that value. This is because `export` only works for subprocesses but not for parent processes. How can I get `export` to make the value permanent?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the export in the file $HOME/.bash_profile and then run the following command:

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```